# Permission to edit Dashboard

Tags: dashboard

I'm trying to make one user be able to edit one Dashboard which has its folder shared with him with EDIT permission.

I've assigned a Permission Set to this user with:

- Manage Dashboards in Public Folders
- Manage Dynamic Dashboards
- Manage All Private Reports and Dashboards
- Edit My Dashboards
- Drag-and-Drop Dashboard Builder
- Create and Customize Dashboards

After adding all those permissions, user can see the edit button on the dashboard, but after trying to edit anything there and pressing save, he gets:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User A creates a dashboard and sets the Viewing As to User B. User C has permissions Manage Dashboards in Public Folders & Manage Dynamic Dashboards. When User C tries to edit a component on the dashboard they get the following error:

"We're having trouble processing your request. Try again, or ask your Salesforce admin for help."

Or

"You don't have permission to edit this dashboard. Ask your Salesforce admin or the dashboard owner for help"

The same thing happens if Viewing As user is set to any other user than the current user viewing the dashboard.

**Workaround**

Give the user View All Data permission or remove View My Team's Dashboards permission.

This is a known issue, refer the [link](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001q7RlQAI&title=can-t-edit-and-save-the-dashboard-when-its-set-to-viewing-as-another-person)