# user not able to edit the dashboard

Tags: lightning

I am system admin. One of my user not able to edit the dashboard. She is getting error message saying " You don't have permission to edit this dashboard. Ask your Salesforce admin or the dashboard owner for help" But she is permitted(edit permission) to all folders in both dashboard and reports. Still she is not able to edit the dashboard. As a admin how Can I help her?

Please suggest.

How to enable "View all data" permission

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission to edit Dashboard](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375162/permission-to-edit-dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you cannot edit a dashboard if it was created by somebody else, ​however you need to have the 'View All Data' permission enabled under system permissions on profile to edit dashboard.

Kindly check limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdmr8UAB/edit-dashboards-created-by-different-user-with-manageedit-permissions).

Also you might want to review [Dashboard access "Insufficient privileges"](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387032&type=1) error.

Thanks!